# PHP cookies not set correctly

Tags: php, setcookie

I have this static function as part of a class.
For some reason `ib_analytics_cf7_action`is set correctly, but `ib_analytics_cf7_name`is not.

Can anyone see a reason for this?

```
public static function insert_contact_form_submit_tracking ($contact_form, $result, $echo=true) {

//I have confirmed the value exists and is a string
setcookie('ib_analytics_cf7_name', $contact_form->title());

switch ($result['status']) {
    case 'validation_failed':
    setcookie('ib_analytics_cf7_action', 'validation_failed');
    break;
    case 'spam':
    setcookie('ib_analytics_cf7_action', 'spam');
    break;
    case 'mail_sent':
    setcookie('ib_analytics_cf7_action', 'mail_sent');
    break;
    case 'mail_failed':
    setcookie('ib_analytics_cf7_action', 'mail_failed');
    break; 
    default :
    return;
}

/*some debugging lines*/
return;
}
```

Comment: try posting the original code. The code posted above looks okay. Both cookie_one and cookie_two should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this less information it's impossible to really answer but it's probably just that the none of the cases are true and the control goes over to the default block.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for misunderstanding your question, one important thing you'll have to remember is that there shouldn't be any output before setting a cookie so make sure that you haven't print or echoed anything, also make sure that there aren't any whitespaces outside of your PHP tags.. That should fix it...

Comment: ok, so it's unlikely to be me misunderstanding the setcookie function itself?

Comment: Yes, I don't think you misunderstood the function itself, but it's impossible to help unless you upload your actual code.. @greengreengrass

Comment: hey. I think you misunderstood the question. The initial cookie is the one not being set correctly. The one managed in the switch is working fine.

Comment: Hey. The function gets called during an ajax request. Any idea how that will affect the output requirements? Do I just need to ensure the Ajax called php files are output free?

Comment: You just have to make sure that the PHP file is output free till the point you set cookies. You can have output after cookie setting is done...

Comment: Hey. Removing all the whitespace from this is going to be too complex, so I'm just going to append the broken cookie value to the working ones. I'll accept the answer - you've been super helpful :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I just mean that you'll have to remove the whitespace outside of your `<?php ?>` tags..